# how to append updated value in existing value for spring mvc form tag

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I am using spring form tag in my application.here **form:textarea path="comment"** is showing the getter method for comment. what I want is to hide the existing value(i.e get method value) from user and append the new value user enter in text area of form to existing value of comment.

for example: existing value is hello for comment and user enter sunshine in text area.when form load it should hide "hello" and append the new value sunshine to existing value.
Final output should be hello sunshine

```
    <tr>
                    <td><label>Comment:</label></td>
                    <td><form:textarea path="comment" /></td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your actual goal is here, but it feels like you are trying to use a wrong methodology for whatever problem you have. Perhaps you should split your stuff to two variables and two inputs. One is of type hidden which contains the previous comment and the other one is textarea which is the new part of comment (initial value is empty). In backend after submit, you concatenate the two variables and show them in the next view as the concatenated String.